# How to delete a particular line and also the line immediately above it

Tags: regex, unix, sed, grep

I found so many examples using sed/grep to able to delete a particular line in a text file but I want to be able to delete that line and the line immediately above it. Any ideas as where I should start?

I have tried sed '/pattern/d' ./file which only delete a particular line.

Comment: Without having tried it, here a suggestion: Incorporate the previous line into your pattern, something along the lines of `^.*\noriginalpattern` - and delete the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;/\nPATTERN/d;P;D' file
```

This keeps 2 lines in the pattern space and if the second line contains the pattern deletes both.

Comment: what does $!N; mean? does it mean any line that is not empty? . i am unable to delete the 2 lines with the above code not sure why?